# Как создать маршрут по маркерам?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api, карты

Нужно накидать на карту много точек, и пользователь должен выбрать интересующие его места, проложить по ним маршрут и отдать на сервер массив маркеров. Может кто делал подобное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кури мануалы по Waypoints and Geolocation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=ru#Waypoints